# How to create an Empty Application in the new Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, templates

Apologies if this has been asked before.

How do I create an Empty Application within the more recent version of Xcode? I'm struggling. A step-by-step guide would be hugely appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first floor is the right answer ,what you actually want to know ?

Comment: I was getting information from unreliable sources and it confused me.

Answer (score 0):

Select File->New->Project and choose "Single View Application[image]"

Comment: I was told that I needed to add some additional code within the "app delegate" and "info.plist" files, is that incorrect?

Comment: Sorry I am not cleat about your question.

Comment: It's ok,sorry, I can't help you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the Xcode app (Version 7.3), click Create a new Xcode project

[image]

2. Choose Single View Application and click Next

[image]

3. Enter the necessary information, such as Product Name, Organisation Name and Organisation Identifier (If you are not in a organisation, just input something), then click Next to save your project to the disk.

[image]

Xcode will automatically create some file for you.

[image]

4. Choose a simulator which to run the application and click the Run button(Or you can press Command+R in your keyboard).

[image]

Since you do not add any code, the simulator simply run a single blank view app. This is a blank application. Usually we view it as a empty application.

Well, you can delete the ViewController.h and ViewController.m and go to Main.storyboard and delete the View Controller Scene below

[image]

Run the application again, this time the simulator only display a black screen.

[image]

You get a empty application.

For more details, please refer to [Start Developing iOS Apps Today](http://everythingcomputerscience.com/books/RoadMapiOS.pdf)

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. :)